# Bluetooth Group Chat For Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to know if it's possible to create Bluetooth Group Chat by using the Sample Bluetooth Chat that is given as an example in the Android SDK. I want to extend that app to allow multiple users to connect to each other, and then they should be able to see each others messages. Basically like Whatsapp running on Bluetooth.

Could someone help me out ?

Comment: you can create seperate socket connections and pass messages - that act like group chat and keeping one device as server and pass messages to all other devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically Yes. You can convert the sample chat app to group chat using multiple socket connection with devices.

BUT BUT....
Practically NO, Because **android currently doesn't support a stable connection with multiple devices** (more than 2 or 3).

So even if you create separate socket connections with each device and pass messages, It will make the Bluetooth connection drop very frequently.

And also even if you make any Android device to a Bluetooth server, How will you manage the connection of that Android Bluetooth server device with multiple Android Bluetooth client devices without connection dropout with stable connection??

SO Practically currently without making a non-android Bluetooth server device you can't create a group chat application on android.

Comment: what if we connect 30 devices in a way to create a network where each device has always connection to one other unique device. Then we could use p2p to share the chat log between the whole group.